# Magnetic quantum number for d orbitals

Tags: hydrogen, orbitals

Online one can find many pictures of d-orbitals.

[image]

I know that these states correspond to :
n = 3, l = 2, m = -2, ...,2

but I don't know which one is which and I couldn't find a clear asignment anywhere. What are the magnetic quantum numbers for each of the above displayed states?

I feel like I should be able to find this everywhere, but I couldn't find any explicit statement.

Comment: The shapes should be related to the spherical harmonic functions, are you familiar with those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no 1:1 relation between $m_l$ and your notation. The wavefunctions like $\psi_{3d_{xy}}$ are constructed as a superpositions of $\psi_{n,l,m_l}$ with different $m_l$.

The (hydrogen-like) wavefunction, depending on $n$, $l$ and $m_l$, looks like

$$\psi_{n,l,m_l}(r,\theta,\varphi) = R(r) Y_l^{m_l}(\theta,\varphi)$$

$Y_l^{m_l}$ is a complex function. Since (or as long as) they are degenerate, you can make linear combinations of these and still get a solution to your original problem. It is possible to get real-valued wavefunction that way:

$$ \psi_{3d_{z^2}} = \psi_{3,2,0} \propto {3z^2-r^2\over r^2}$$
$$ \psi_{3d_{xz}} = {1\over{\sqrt2}}(\psi_{3,2,-1}-\psi_{3,2,+1}) \propto {xz\over r^2}$$
$$ \psi_{3d_{yz}} = {1\over{\sqrt{2i}}}(\psi_{3,2,-1}+\psi_{3,2,+1}) \propto {yz\over r^2}$$
$$ \psi_{3d_{x^2-y^2}} = {1\over{\sqrt{2}}}(\psi_{3,2,-2}+\psi_{3,2,+2}) \propto {x^2-y^2\over r^2}$$
$$ \psi_{3d_{xy}} = {1\over{\sqrt{2i}}}(\psi_{3,2,-2}-\psi_{3,2,+2}) \propto {xy\over r^2}$$

It should be clear why these combinations are named that way ($d_{z^2}$ is sometimes actually called $d_{3z^2-r^2}$ because of this).

Because drawing the imaginary part of $Y_l^{m_l}$ is a hassle, pictures oftentimes silently ignore that and actually draw the linear combinations, and since you always combine $-m_l$ and $+m_l$ (for higher $l$ too), the difference is often not relevant (because a lot of effects depend on the absolute value of $m_l$). But when you attend your solid state (or molecular) physics lectures, you will need that.

Comment: So the picture posted by Spectra is wrong?

Comment: @Stein The picture is correct, just the interpretation that $m_l=2 \Leftrightarrow d_{xy}$ is not. The basic shape stays the same, just the imaginary part isn't shown, and the axis are arbitrary for a free atom. You might get in trouble when you have fixed axis (e.g. when your atom is in a solid crystal), because then it will get relevant to understand some things. And when you have to calculate stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I got this one. Does this help ?
The subscript of d represents the m value.
[image]

Link :http://study.com/academy/lesson/electron-orbital-definition-shells-shapes.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Image Source: [Spherical Harmonic Functions](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)

The shapes are related to the spherical harmonic functions, and as you can see from the picture above, given the correct $l $ and $m $ numbers, you should be able to match up the orbitals to the appropiate functions.

Source: [Spherical Harmonic Functions And Electron Orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)

> Spherical harmonics are important in many theoretical and practical applications, e.g., the representation of multipole electrostatic and electromagnetic fields, **computation of atomic orbital electron configurations**,[my emphasis]  representation of gravitational fields, geoids, and the magnetic fields of planetary bodies and stars, and characterization of the cosmic microwave background radiation.